# How to invoke a PHP script using shell script?

Tags: php, linux, shell

I am setting a cron job on my linux server.

So i am writing a shell script for it,which invoke after every 20 minutes.

In this shell script i need to do following:

I want to executed a php script if something changed(in last 20 min) in mydata.csv file.

So plese tell me how can i do this?

-Thanks

Comment: You want to check if the file changed and then execute the php script, or just execute the php script every 20 minutes? You can just run 'php path/to/file.php' to execute a php file in shell.

Comment: i want if the file changes then execute php script

Comment: i think i can do it in a other way also that execute php after every 20 min then check the file changes then do some stuff otherwise not.But please suggest me how can i do this in a php?if you hope this is also a correct way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Check the last modified date on the CSV file and compare it to the current time (not on a *nix machine right now, Google it)
2. Execute the PHP script

   ```
   /usr/bin/php /path/to/php/script.php
   ```

*Disclaimer: The path to your PHP binary may differ*

Also see http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/programming-scripting/107278-how-prgrammatically-compare-file-timestamp-against-currrent-time.html

Comment: thanks i got your point but still i have a query:stat -c "%y" file this will return me something like this "2011-08-10 11:36:48.000000000 +0530" and date +%s -d '20 minute ago' will give like this:1312956839   and i know that 20*60=1200 sec in 20 minutes but plz tell me  how can i compare that file has been modified or not ?

Answer (score 0):

just call php from it

```
php myScript.php
```